# visual basic 6 ActiveX control

Tags: vb6

I am developing simple active x control with VB6 . i am putting debug.print in control initialized event to test how it is initialized . I am using new vb form (for testing activex), to put ActiveX control and watching  intermediate window for debug print , but nothing happen but MsgBOX function work ok. why debug.print is not working when method is called ? in container form It is mentioned in visual basic 6 secrets book but not working in my case

Comment: Did you try "print" statement in intermediate window? is it working

Comment: Could you please post your debug statement

Comment: please post what you done so far

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not running your ActiveX control (OCX) within the same Visual Basic Group (VBG) so the control cannot access the debug/immediate window for the parent form application.

The solution is to load your form project and add click "File->Add Project" and select your existing ActiveX control project. Now when you debug you will see the messages from the OCX when you debug your form. In fact, you'll be able to step through all of the ActiveX code in a single debug session with one IDE loaded so it will accelerate your development when making changes to the control.